# WiFi path loss formula

Tags: wifi

I am referring to the Wi-Fi path loss formulas:

2.4 GHz: L = 46 + 25log(d)

5 GHz: L = 53 + 30log(d)

I see they slightly differ from the Free Space Path Loss formula. I want to know why and how did they get derived?

Formulas can be found here: https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1000113315/ad382ac7/network-coverage-design

Comment: They don’t quite explain how they get to that formula. The 20 factor in the free space loss formula is quite a direct deduction: factor 10 because of the **deci**bels and factor 2 because of the square. Frequency has a separate influence on the formula which ends up as a constant, not a factor. Either they try to include loss due to obstacles (but they seem to account for that separately) or maybe for obstacles in the Fresnel zone. In any case, indoors or in any environment without line of sight it’s just pure speculation. Obstacles and multi path are very difficult to model accurately.

Comment: [A taste of several path loss propagation models commonly used](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1003/1/012028/pdf#:~:text=Path%20loss%20propagation%20models%20is,dataset%20collected%20from%20specific%20environments.) - try and find one that is closest to yours.

Comment: @Andy aka Is the link valid? I cannot open it.

Comment: Yes, it opens. The document is called "Analyzing Study of Path loss Propagation Models in Wireless Communications at 0.8 GHz" if you want to search for it instead.